# Wrong encoding of text, in Django?

Tags: python, django, templates, encoding, utf-8

```
"query" = джазовыми
```

For some reason...when I display it via:

```
{{ query|safe }}
```

I get this:

```
%u0434%u0436%u0430%u0437%u043E%u0432%u044B%u043C%u0438
```

Comment: I assume that `"query" = джазовыми` should read `query = "джазовыми"`?

Comment: Is the string you quoted from the source of the page, or is that what gets displayed from the browser?

Comment: It's from the displayed browser.

Comment: and if you remove the safe filter, it displays without problem?

Comment: I'm confused as to where the percent-u-four-digits escape came from. This is the non-standard format normally only produced by the JavaScript `escape` function (it's not proper URL escaping and `escape` should generally not be used for anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the query be set from the source, this would solve it:

```
query = u"джазовыми"
```

(provided that for example your file encoding is utf-8 and you have corresponding line

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

in the beginning)

But I guess the query is entered by user. The error seems to be located in that part of your code. Can you quote how it is done?